# How to use Sandbox for Website Payments Standard?

Tags: testing, paypal, paypal-sandbox

So I've heard that the test environment provided by PayPal Sandbox is **PayPal Pro**. My company is **not** using PayPal Pro, we're using the following: Website Payments Standard, ButtonManagerAPI to create dynamic hosted buttons, and an IPN listener.

How can I make sure my sandbox environment accurately represents Standard Payments? It's no good if I'm offering Standard Payments to my customers but testing my site for PayPal Pro, I might miss something!

Answer (score 1):

You can test Website Payments Standard with the sandbox. You would just want to set up a test sandbox business account to be used as the seller, and then create a test sandbox buyer account.  Then you can test with Website Payments Standard, and the ButtonManager API calls.  You do not have to use the Website Payments Pro features.  Even Website Payments Pro accounts, can still use standard.  Website Payments Standard is not disabled on Pro accounts just because they are using Pro.

Answer (score 1):

this is directed to @PP_MTS_Chad (sorry to do it from here but, I have NO idea how to get around in StackOverflow):  I too am testing payments standard in the sandbox.  weird thing happened... in the last display page where the payment is verified, there used to be a link where I could click to get back to seller website.  that link is now missing in the sandbox.  where did it go?  how do I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

** mystery solved! **  with regard to missing return link to seller website...
CLEAR YOUR BROWSER CACHE AND TRY AGAIN!!    ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is [the link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_test-pps-buttons/) to PayPal's instructions on how to test PayPal Standard.